# sql only inserts some data in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using data from an activation email. $email & $key.

$result1 mysql_query -

The result is that only the `email`, `role`, `credits` are inserted into table `users`. Data items `username`, `password` are not inserted.

$result2 mysql_query -

The data is not deleted from table `tempusers`

If I echo the data from the while loop the correct data is returned.

Got to be something simple but I just cannot see it. Thanks.

CODE:

```
include 'core/init.php';  /* database connection*/

if (isset($_GET['email']) &&        preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",      $_GET['email'])){
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
}

if(isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32)) {
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($_get['key']);
}

if(isset($email) && isset($key)) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempusers` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `activation` = '$key' ") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['user_id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($row['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($row['password']);


}


$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `role`, `credits`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', 'user', 0)") or die(mysql_error());


$result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `tempusers` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$result1) {
echo "Oops your account could not be activated. Please contact the system administrator!";
} else {
header('Location: prompt.php?x=0');

}   

} else {
echo "Error. Please contact the system administrator!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `$_get` in => `mysql_real_escape_string($_get['key'])` is in lowercase letters.

`$_GET` is a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and it **must** be set in uppercase letters like this => `$_GET`

---

***Sidenote:*** I noticed that you are using the word `key` in `$_GET['key']` etc.

If your other script happens to be using this word as a column reference, you will need to set it inside backticks, since `key` is a MySQL [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). *I'm just thinking outloud here.*

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

Plus, I recommend you use [**`mysqli_` functions with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Changed to $_GET['key']. Also added error_reporting. I note your comments re mysqli etc. Which I intend to change after I have things working. So far no change to situation and no errors reported. Thanks

Comment: @kevo Did adding error reporting give you back any errors?

Comment: @kevo Also, add `echo $result1;` or `var_dump($result1);` right after `$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO...` to see what's being passed through, as well as using `var_dump();` on all of your other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the query goes execute? And are you also sure the query have at least 1 result? The `$email` is already set but to set the username and passwors your query needs to have at least 1 result.

I also noticed `$_get['key']` but i am not sure if its neccecary to change it to `$_GET['key']`.

Comment: As some of the data is inserted I guess the query has at least one result. Thanks

Comment: It is possible that the insert query will execute while the select query has no results. Read the comment of Fred. It is highly recommended to turn on error_repporting.

Comment: [SOLVED] Sorted out a few problems stemming from $key code.

Comment: $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `role`, `credits`) 
    SELECT `username`, `email`, `password`, 'admin', 0
    FROM `tempusers`
    WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `activation` = '$key' ");

    $result2 = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM `tempusers`
    WHERE `email` = '$email' ");